# Can a Skeleton created by Animate Dead use different equipment?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, equipment, undead

The description of the Animate Dead spell states:

> The target becomes a skeleton if you chose bones or a zombie if you chose a corpse (the DM has the creature’s game statistics).

Assuming this means that the skeleton should use the statistics listed in the MM, I'd expect that a skeleton is able to use a shortsword and a shortbow. Would an animated skeleton be able to use any of the following equipment instead? Would it be considered proficient in said equipment if so?

- A weapon of a different type (e.g. a longsword, longbow, crossbow)
- A magic weapon of the same type (e.g. a +1 shortsword)
- A shield
- Armour